# How to organize the JSON information inside a table?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

The first problem was solved, thanks to my good friends who answered my question and gave me the best solutions, but now i'm facing a new "problem"

I've created a table to show up the data in JSON format, but i still want to organize and separate the data contained inside the JSON

Here's how it looking right now:

[Actual table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhNEs.png)

And that's how i want to show the information:

[Objective table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTd0J.png)

That's the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <th>Longitude</th>
        <th>Inf. Data</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let device of devices | async">
          <td>{{device.key}}</td>
          <td>|-8.8780555725098|</td>
          <td>|-36.463222503662|</td>
          <td>2019-05-07T07:42:31Z</td>
          <!--<td>{{device.key}}</td>
          <td>{{device | json}}</td>
          <td><button (click)="getCurrentDevice(device)" mat-button>More</button></td>-->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  devices: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    let list = db.list('/busao/devices');
    this.devices = list.snapshotChanges()
    list.snapshotChanges().subscribe(console.log)

    /*this.devices_values = db.list('/busao/devices').valueChanges();*/

  }

  getCurrentDevice(device): void{
    console.log(device);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this {{device.value}} only. And if $ is coming from API then use {{device['$value']}}

See what is coming from api, try to read the structure of API and dont get confused between array and object.

As there is no key with name value so you can display these things only as per your API data,

`{{device.payload}}` or `{{device.type}}` or `{{device.prevKey}}` or `{{device.key}}`

**Try This**

```
{{device.payload.location.latitude}}
{{device.payload.location.longitude}}
{{device.payload.location.update}}
```

Comment: What is the error and see what is coming in response of API.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but i can see the data on the console, but on the page is not showing the values

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of that console?

Comment: As I can see that there is no key with name value, so you can only print like this

{{device.payload}} or {{device.type}} or {{device.prevKey}} or {{device.key}}

Comment: Try one of these key and see the result.

Comment: I've used the {{device.key}}

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to show the other values that are contained inside the device keys? Like the first photo that i put from the database structure

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote the answer and check ok.

Comment: Thanks again my friend, i've tried to do this way, but i've got the following error: "Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

By calling `subscribe()`, you are consuming the data in your code. Instead you'll want to bind `valueChanges` stream to the component, so that the UI gets notified and can render the list:

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.devices = db.list('/busao/devices').valueChanges();
```

If you want to both bind the list to the UI *and* show its data in the console, you can do:

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  let list = db.list('/busao/devices');
  this.devices = list.valueChanges()
  list.valueChanges().subscribe(console.log)
  // or: list.auditTrail().subscribe(console.log)
```

Also see the AngularFire2 documentation on [retrieving data as lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#retrieve-data).

Comment: Thank you very much mate :D

Comment: I want to show the key of the device above the json information, i was trying to bind your information to show the data and the solution that the guy before you that answered me, but the key isn't appearing

Comment: If you also want to show the key use `snapshotChanges` stream instead of `valueChanges`.